# How to call Rust from JS and back?

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, circular-dependency, wasm-bindgen

I'm trying to adapt the [game of life tutorial](https://rustwasm.github.io/book/game-of-life/hello-world.html) to call user-defined JS (instead of `alert`) from Rust:

index.js:

```js
import * as wasm from "testing-wasm";

export const jsfunc = () => {
  console.log("jsfunc called");
};

// Call Rust from JS. This function will call `jsfunc`, declared above.
wasm.rustfunc();
```

lib.rs:

```rust
mod utils;

use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

// When the `wee_alloc` feature is enabled, use `wee_alloc` as the global
// allocator.
#[cfg(feature = "wee_alloc")]
#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: wee_alloc::WeeAlloc = wee_alloc::WeeAlloc::INIT;

#[wasm_bindgen(module = "/www/index.js")]
extern "C" {
    fn jsfunc();
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn rustfunc() {
    // call JS
    jsfunc();
}
```

`wasm-pack build` runs fine. But running the web project (`npm run start`) can't resolve the import anymore:

```
ERROR in ../pkg/snippets/testing-wasm-8ea926e8de57779d/www/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'testing-wasm' in '/Users/ischuetz/dev/ct-an/testing-wasm/pkg/snippets/testing-wasm-8ea926e8de57779d/www'
 @ ../pkg/snippets/testing-wasm-8ea926e8de57779d/www/index.js 1:0-37 7:0-13
 @ ../pkg/testing_wasm_bg.wasm
 @ ../pkg/testing_wasm.js
 @ ./index.js
 @ ./bootstrap.js
```

It works before introducing the circular dependency.

Any ideas? I also found [import_js](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/tree/master/examples/import_js) in wasm-bindgen but there's no direct call to Rust from JS.

Answer (score 2):

in your `Cargo.toml` file add this:

```
[lib]
# if you want to integrate your rust code with javascript we use cdylib
crate-type=["cdylib"]
```

since you are using `wasm-bindgen` and `wee_alloc` and I assume it is already in your .toml file:

```
[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen="0.2.63"
wee_alloc="0.4.5"
```

When you build your code, `pkg` folder is created which includes glue javascript code wasm code. Now you need to get this `pkg` folder into the node modules. To do so, you have to link it to your javascript project's `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    // your path to ../pkg might be different
    "rust_project": "file:../pkg",
  },
```

Then in your javascript project directory, `npm install`. You will see that `rust_project` module is in your node_modules directory.

In your javascript file:

```
import rustfunc from "rust_project";
```

Now you can call your function

Comment: It's a good answer if you're talking about nodejs. Is it possible to do this in the browser?

Comment: @Squirrel in order to use it for browser the only difference is the building command `wasm-pack build --target web `. eventually `wasm-pack` creates  a module and then you need to load this module in your project through package.json dependencies